# Is it possible to detect if the object that a bound member function refers to is deleted or destroyed

Tags: c++, function, pointers, bind

I am exploring the use of `std::function` and `std::bind`. I see that you can bind a member function, for example:

```
class A{
    int c_ = 10;
public:
    int add(int a, int b){
        return a + b + c_;
    }
};
int main(){
    A* p_a = new A;
    std::function<int()> f = std::bind(&A::add, p_a, 1, 1);
    printf("%i\n", f()); // yields "12" (1 + 1 + 10)
    delete p_a;
    printf("%i\n", f()); // yields derpy numbers, no errors thrown.
}
```

Is there a way to detect if p_a has been deleted?

My solution to do this is having a wrapper class that holds the function and a `weak_ptr` to the object. I am just wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: You can use smart pointers for this (instead of raw pointers), in particular: `std::shared_ptr<A>` and `std::weak_ptr<A>`.

Comment: There's no way to detect when a pointer has been deleted. You should avoid creating situations where an object doesn't know whether some other object it wants to access is still alive. Smart pointers are the way to go here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so as long as the `std::function` exists the object will exist?

Comment: @MichaelMitchell I was thinking in the direction that the `std::weak_ptr<A>` is used for `std::bind()`, and you can check it before calling `f()`. But of course you can bind the `shared_ptr<A>` as well, and it will guarantee that lifetime of `A` ends no earlier than `f` is in scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::bind` can accept smart pointers, so you can simply pass `std::shared_ptr<A>` to it.

```
std::shared_ptr<A> p_a(new A);
std::function<int()> f = std::bind(&A::add, p_a, 1, 1);
```

Note, that the functor will own the object: the object will live as long as the functor lives. If you don't want such behavior, then your solution with a `weak_ptr` wrapper is nice.

Comment: So if `std::bind` is passed a `shared_ptr` the object in the `shared_ptr` will not be deleted as long as the function exists? Your edit answers this.

Comment: With my wrapper class idea, if I wanted to have a class that made a bind of one of its functions, would I have to `enable_shared_from` in order to pass a proper `weak_ptr` to the wrapper?

Comment: @MichaelMitchell Yes. That's the classic use case for `shared_from_this`.

Comment: @MichaelMitchell if you have no way to get a smart pointer to this in some class method, then you have to use `enable_shared_from_this`. Note that it is not necessary if the binding happens outside class.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct A{
  int c_ = 10;
  int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b + c_;
  }
};
template<class T>
std::weak_ptr<T> weak( std::shared_ptr<T> const& sp ) { return {sp}; }

int main(){
  auto p_a = std::make_shared<A>();
  std::function<int()> f = [w_a = weak(p_a)]() {
    if (auto p_a = w_a.lock())
      return p_a->add(1,1);
    throw w_a;
  }
  printf("%i\n", f()); // yields "12" (1 + 1 + 10)
  p_a.reset();
  try {
    printf("%i\n", f()); // yields derpy numbers, no errors thrown.
  } catch( std::weak_ptr<A> wp ) {
    printf("object deleted\n");
  }
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55bb7ca6ec7412fc).

in general, in C++ you don't pay for what you don't use.

Tracking the lifetime of objects has a cost.  If you want to track the lifetime of objects, you can use a `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr` to the (free-store) allocated object, or use a `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` (uniquely) owned by the object to indicate its lifetime is over.

The above is an implementation using C++14 lambdas to capture the object's shared pointer as a weak ptr, and give defined behavior (a throw of a copy of said weak pointer) if it has been deleted.

A lifetime token looks like:

```
using lifetime_token = std::weak_ptr<void>;
struct has_lifetime {
  has_lifetime():token(std::make_shared<char>()) {}
  has_lifetime(has_lifetime const&o):has_lifetime() {} // not default
  lifetime_token get_lifetime() const {
    return token;
  }
private:
  std::shared_ptr<void> token;
};
```

inheriting from `has_lifetime` gives you a `get_lifetime()` member that exists for as long as you do (it is destroyed by your destructor, and can no longer be `.lock()`d).

This is an easier pattern to follow if you cannot modify the ownership semantics of the original class.  Simply `.lock()` the `lifetime_token` of the object to determine if it is still alive.